# Websocket Ionic 3 Angular 4

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic3

How to get a Websocket in Ionic 3 and Angular 4 working?

I tried the class socket.io-client but if i connect the websocket like this

```
this.socket = io(this.urls.websocket,{transports: ['websocket']};
```

this.socket is undefined and user at the Server is shown as connected. Disconnect will not be triggered.

If i use the integrated Websocket class like this

```
this.socket = new WebSocket(this.urls.websocket,['websocket']);
console.log("Socket ready state" + this.socket.readyState);
console.log("Socket:" + console.dir(this.socket));
```

The Socket is shown at the server as connected too and disconnect will not be triggered, but at the client i get an error message:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.0.10:8000/node/test.js' failed:
>   Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

this.socket is after the connect line in connecting mode (line 2) and if i log error a second time (line 3) its disconnected at the client.
Bit at the server it will be shown still as connected and disconnected wont be triggered.

With other clients like an other nodeserver i don't have any problems and everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `io.connect`.

Try this:

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

this.socket = io.connect(this.socketURL);
```